# Problem with inverting function to form $y=f(x)$

Tags: inverse-function

As in the title. Here are my attempts and the given function:

> Given function:  $y=\frac {\log_2{x}-3}{2x}      $
>
> Inverse function: $$ x= \frac {\log_2{y}-3}{2y}             $$
>   $$2xy=\log_2{y}-3        $$
>   $$ 2^{2xy}=\frac y8     $$

At this step i'm stuck, and dont know what to do next

Comment: Try using the Lambert function : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @almagest The second one,as written above

Comment: @almagest But ive never written something like that in my post

Comment: @almagest Oh yes, and the problem is to inverse that, i think it is necessary to a problem to write what we come from

Comment: @almagest It also replaces 2x with 2y: it comes from definition of inverting relations

Comment: @almagest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function Look at "Graph of the inverse" section

Comment: @almagest Yes you do, but function $x^2$ doesnt have inverse function, but it has inverse relation which is: $y^2=x$

Comment: @almagest Just plug into desmos some random f and then replace x with y, and u will see that graph of this equation is reflected to line y=x

Comment: @1qwertyyyy I think it is bad practice to switch $x$ and $y$. It would be better to express the inverse function as $x=g(y)$. But leaving that aside Tuvasbien gave you the answer: use the Lambert W function. You cannot express the inverse in terms of elementary functions. You need Lambert W.

Comment: @almagest Ok,can u help me with that?